# How to prevent focus/autofocus on first form input with bootstrap/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making some changes to an application using jQuery 3.4 + Bootstrap 3.4.
I have added a form to the end of the page, which has the undesired side effect of the browser putting the focus on the first input element of that form (checkbox). This is the first and only form on the page.
The page is quite long, so this results in the browser scrolling down on page load, which I do not want.

Form looks like this:

```
<form id="edit_notifications_form" method="post" action="/product/2/edit_notifications">
<span class="centered"><input id="engagement_added_slack" type="checkbox" name="engagement_added" value="slack"></span>
```

At first I was suspecting bootstrap is doing this for all forms, but I can't find any documentation about it and even see people asking questions on how to achieve the "auto focus on first input element". So it must be some other javascript library doing this.

[image]

I have searched my codebase but there is no focus/autofocus/scroll/tabindex at all in my codebase. I went through the bootstrap css and js files, but no obvious stuff around autofocus.

package-json looks like this:

```
    "JUMFlot": "jumjum123/JUMFlot#*",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.0",
"bootstrap-social": "^4.0.0",
"bootstrap-wysiwyg": "^2.0.0",
"bootswatch": "3.4.1",
"chosen": "harvesthq/bower-chosen#~1.4.0",
"chosen-bootstrap": "dbtek/chosen-bootstrap#~1.1.0",
"components-jqueryui": "^1.0.0",
"datatables": "1.10.18",
"drmonty-datatables-plugins": "^1.0.0",
"drmonty-datatables-responsive": "^1.0.0",
"flot": "flot/flot#~0.8.3",
"flot-axis": "markrcote/flot-axislabels#*",
"font-awesome": "^4.0.0",
"fullcalendar": "^3.0.0",
"google-code-prettify": "^1.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.4.0",
"jquery-highlight": "3.5.0",
"jquery.cookie": "1.4.1",
"jquery.flot.tooltip": "^0.9.0",
"jquery.hotkeys": "jeresig/jquery.hotkeys#master",
"justgage": "^1.3.0",
"metismenu": "~3.0.6",
"moment": "^2.0.0",
"morris.js": "morrisjs/morris.js",
"simplemde": "^1.0.0",
"startbootstrap-sb-admin-2": "1.0.7"
```

How do I go about finding out which javascript library is causing this autofocus / autoscroll?

Comment: turns out there was some code in my project, but it was excluded from visual studio code search so it didn't hit when search for 'focus' :-(

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was some code in my project, but it was excluded from visual studio code search so it didn't hit when search for 'focus' :-( –